# How to change the arrow of the vector command?

Tags: arrows, tikz-arrows, vector

Is it possible to use the (stealth) type arrow in the `\vec` command?

In the `tikz` environment I use something like `(\draw[>=stealth,->] (A) -- (B);)` to change the arrow. I want to use this same typo of arrow outside the `tikz` environment, for example when I use the vector command `\vec{v}`.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [esvect](https://ctan.org/pkg/esvect) package you may just get to what you need !

Try options `[d]` or `[b]` when loading the package.
Use command `\vv{arg}` to obtain the arrowed symbols.

Comment: Or even  [e] is close.

Comment: I did not put it because it looked a bit shrinked, but you're right

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid not. But you can use the `esvect` package, which has nice arrows tips (8 kinds in all). Furthermore these arrows are extensible, and called with the command `\vv`.  If your vector, say e_r, has an index, use `\vv*{e}{r}`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try manually like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
%opening
\title{}
\author{}
\def\tikzmark#1{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]\node(#1){};\end{tikzpicture}}


\makeatletter
\renewcommand\vec[1]{\ifdefined\xsh\relax\else\pgfmathsetmacro\xs{\f@size/3}\def\xsh{\xs pt}\fi\ifdefined\ysh\relax\else\pgfmathsetmacro\ys{\f@size/1.3}\xdef\ysh{\ys pt}\fi\tikzmark{VecStart}#1\tikzmark{VecStop}\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]\draw[->,>=stealth]($(VecStart)+(\xsh,\ysh)$)--($(VecStop)+(-\xsh,\ysh)$);\end{tikzpicture}\let\xsh=\undefined\let\ysh=\undefined}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

$\vec{AB}$

\xdef\xsh{5pt}
\xdef\ysh{14pt}
$$\displaystyle\int\vec{\displaystyle\frac{AB}{3}}dx$$

\end{document}
```

It is not very easy in usage. You have to define `\xsh` and `\ysh` every time before use if you want to control the placing of the arrow.

It is just an idea not really worked as it could and I just adding for plurality.

Output:

[image]