# How to prevent tikzpicture contents from going outside of document bounds?

Tags: tikz-pgf, line-breaking, nodes, width

I need text inside "node" command to automatically break at document margin and transition to next line as it does outside of tikzpicture.

```
\documentclass
    [%
        border=10mm,
        varwidth=100mm
    ]   {standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \path node
            {%
one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve thirteen fourteen
            };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Desired outcome:

[image]

Comment: `node[text width=\linewidth]`

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I didn't thought about your answer but you also need [inner sep=0]. ( I just learned from John's first comment here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/394630/120578)

Comment: @koleygr That's true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use a minipage:

```
\documentclass
    [%
        border=10mm,
        varwidth=100mm
    ]   {standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0]
        \path node
            {%
            \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve thirteen fourteen
            \end{minipage}%
            };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

"inner sep=0" option saves you from overfull hbox.

Comment: Might be useful to include a `\noindent` _before_ the `tikzpicture` and a trailing `%` as in `\end{minipage}%`. The `%` may be ok in this specfic case, but won't be in general following an `\end{minipage}`.

Comment: @PeterGrill In this case (with `standalone`) the `\noindent` doesn't matter.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. The question title is more general. I think that Peter commented for the general case. I just show that he talks about the % for the general case but the \noindent is for general usage too...